# Undefined Auth0 dependencies

Tags: php, lumen, auth0

I have a Lumen application by following this tutorial ( [Tutoorial Lumen](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-lumen/) )

I ran this command : `composer require auth0/auth0-php` , it works without failure
And after that I put that in my Middleware ->

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth0\SDK\Exception\InvalidTokenException;
use Auth0\SDK\Helpers\JWKFetcher;
use Auth0\SDK\Helpers\Tokens\AsymmetricVerifier;
use Auth0\SDK\Helpers\Tokens\TokenVerifier;
```

But, when I have that part of the code :

```
public function validateToken($token)
    {
        try {
            $jwksUri = env('AUTH0_DOMAIN') . '.well-known/jwks.json';
            $jwksFetcher = new JWKFetcher(null, [ 'base_uri' => $jwksUri ]);
            $signatureVerifier = new AsymmetricVerifier($jwksFetcher);
            $tokenVerifier = new TokenVerifier(env('AUTH0_DOMAIN'), env('AUTH0_AUD'), $signatureVerifier);

            $decoded = $tokenVerifier->verify($token);
        }
        catch(InvalidTokenException $e) {
            throw $e;
        };
    }
```

I have error on every Auth0 things :

- Undefined type 'Auth0\SDK\Helpers\JWKFetcher'
- Undefined type 'Auth0\SDK\Helpers\Tokens\AsymmetricVerifier'
- Undefined type 'Auth0\SDK\Helpers\Tokens\TokenVerifier'
- Undefined type 'Auth0\SDK\Exception\InvalidTokenException'

Someone know why ?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: at the risk of stating the absolute obvious, are you already including `autoload.php` in the `vendor` directory at all/by this point?

Comment: just downgrade to auth0/auth0-php to v7.1